# ecryptfs size different from home directory size

Tags: linux, ubuntu-11.04, diskspace, ecryptfs

I'm puzzled. My harddisk is full and most of the space is used by .eryptfs/$MYUSERNAME (810.4 GB). Strangly, my home directory /home/MYUSERNAME (22.2GB) consumes significantly less diskspace. Any idea what is wrong or where to look for the "missing" free space?

Answer (score 3):

eCryptfs *slightly* pads files, and the overhead of encryption will slightly increase your over all disk usage, but *certainly* not to the degree you describe, ***37x***!

The only disk usage that really matters is that of your `/home/.ecryptfs/$USER` directory, which is really where the encrypted files are stored on disk.  What you're seeing in terms of the usage of $HOME is really phantom -- the cleartext decryption of those files only appears in memory, and not on disk.

To see your true usage, use:

```
df -h /home
du -sh /home
```